# Logins like user@ad.foo cause profile files to be owned by root

Tags: login, pam, ldap, active-directory, sssd

The users at my school are used to logging in to email, windows etc with a login `username@ad.foo` (authenticated with Active Directory via LDAP). Unfortunately this is causing havoc and corrupting their user profile.

**UPDATE - CAUSE:**
This was caused by some custom modifications in our setup that I didn't know about and were before my time. Was a bit difficult for me to find.

Custom code was in: `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`
Which ran a script that executed `chown -R ${PAM_USER}. ${HOME_DIR}`. When users logged in as username@ad.foo this becomes `chown -R username@ad.foo. ${HOME_DIR}`.

**Problem login: username@xyz**

New user logs in as `username@ad.foo`. LDAP authenticates with AD and accepts the login. System attempts to create new user profile in /home.. however the system fails somewhere and the new profile is owned by root.

**Working login: username**

If the user logs in the first time as just `username` then all is well. LDAP authenticated with AD, account is created and has correct owner.

**System:**

- OS: KUbuntu 22.04 LTS. Error occurs on KUbuntu 20.04 LTS also
- Authentication: LDAP (via SSSD)

**How to attack this problem?**

- Can sddm or sssd filter out everything after "@..." ?
- Which process actually copies /etc/skel then does chown ?
- How to debug ?

**Log Files**

```
auth.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 sddm-helper: pam_unix(sddm:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost=  user=u5371234@ad.foo
auth.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 sddm-helper: pam_sss(sddm:auth): authentication success; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost= user=u5371234@ad.foo
auth.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 sddm-helper: pam_succeed_if(sddm:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000000" was met by user "u5371234@ad.foo"                                                        
auth.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 sddm-helper: pam_exec(sddm:auth): Calling /bin/bash ...                                                         
auth.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 sddm-helper: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file                                                           
auth.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 sddm-helper: gkr-pam: stashed password to try later in open session                                       
auth.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 sddm-helper: pam_kwallet5(sddm:auth): pam_kwallet5: pam_sm_authenticate                                                                                               
auth.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 sddm-helper: pam_kwallet5(sddm:setcred): pam_kwallet5: pam_sm_setcred                                  
auth.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 sddm-helper: pam_unix(sddm:session): session opened for user u5371234@ad.foo(uid=15371234) by (uid=0)                                                         
auth.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 systemd-logind[1177]: New session 3 of user u5371234.                                                                                                                  
auth.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user u5371234(uid=15371234) by (uid=0)                                               
auth.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 sddm-helper: pam_unix(sddm-greeter:session): session closed for user sddm                                                                                              
auth.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 systemd-logind[1177]: Session 1 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.             
auth.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 systemd-logind[1177]: Removed session 1.                                                                                                                               
auth.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 sddm-helper: gkr-pam: gnome-keyring-daemon started properly and unlocked keyring
auth.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 sddm-helper: pam_kwallet5(sddm:session): pam_kwallet5: pam_sm_open_session                                                                                            
auth.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 sddm-helper: pam_kwallet5(sddm:session): pam_kwallet5: Couldn't create salt file                       
auth.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 sddm-helper: pam_kwallet5(sddm:session): pam_kwallet5: Couldn't read salt file                                                                                        
auth.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 sddm-helper: pam_kwallet5(sddm:session): pam_kwallet5: Fail into creating the hash
auth.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 sddm-helper: pam_unix(sddm:session): session closed for user u5371234@ad.foo                                                                                  
auth.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 sddm-helper: pam_kwallet5(sddm:session): pam_kwallet5: pam_sm_close_session                                                                                            
auth.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 sddm-helper: pam_kwallet5(sddm:setcred): pam_kwallet5: pam_sm_setcred
auth.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 systemd-logind[1177]: Session 3 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.                                                                                             

daemon.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 systemd[1]: Starting SSSD PAM Service responder private socket...
daemon.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 systemd[1]: Starting SSSD PAM Service responder socket...                                                                                                            
daemon.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 systemd[1]: Starting SSSD PAC Service responder... 
daemon.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 sssd_check_socket_activated_responders[1525]: [sssd] [main] (0x0070): Misconfiguration found for the pam responder.                                                  
daemon.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 sssd_check_socket_activated_responders[1525]: The pam responder has been configured to be socket-activated but it's still mentioned in the services' line in /etc/sss
d/sssd.conf.                                                                                                                                                                                               
daemon.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 sssd_check_socket_activated_responders[1525]: Please, consider either adjusting your services' line in /etc/sssd/sssd.conf or disabling the pam's socket by calling:
daemon.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 sssd_check_socket_activated_responders[1525]: "systemctl disable sssd-pam.socket"                                                                                    
daemon.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 systemd[1]: sssd-pam-priv.socket: Control process exited, code=exited, status=17/n/a
daemon.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 systemd[1]: sssd-pam-priv.socket: Failed with result 'exit-code'.                                                                                                    
daemon.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 systemd[1]: Failed to listen on SSSD PAM Service responder private socket.           
daemon.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for SSSD PAM Service responder socket.                                                                                                 
daemon.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 systemd[1]: sssd-pam.socket: Job sssd-pam.socket/start failed with result 'dependency'.              
daemon.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 sssd_check_socket_activated_responders[1526]: [sssd] [main] (0x0070): Misconfiguration found for the pam responder.
daemon.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 sssd_check_socket_activated_responders[1526]: The pam responder has been configured to be socket-activated but it's still mentioned in the services' line in /etc/sss
d/sssd.conf.                                                                       
daemon.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 sssd_check_socket_activated_responders[1526]: Please, consider either adjusting your services' line in /etc/sssd/sssd.conf or disabling the pam's socket by calling:
daemon.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 sssd_check_socket_activated_responders[1526]: "systemctl disable sssd-pam.socket"
daemon.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 systemd[1]: Started SSSD PAC Service responder.
daemon.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 systemd[1]: sssd-pam.socket: Control process exited, code=exited, status=17/n/a
daemon.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 systemd[1]: sssd-pam.socket: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
daemon.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 systemd[1]: Closed SSSD PAM Service responder socket.
daemon.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 sssd_pac[1528]: Starting up
daemon.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of UID 15371234.
daemon.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 systemd[1]: Starting User Runtime Directory /run/user/15371234...
daemon.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 systemd[1]: Finished User Runtime Directory /run/user/15371234.
daemon.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 15371234...
daemon.log.1:Jul 26 15:26:43 linux042 systemd[1546]: Failed to open configuration file '/home/u5371234/.config/systemd/user.conf': Permission denied
```

Comment: You’re welcome … I apparently misinterpreted your question as a home directory creation issue while it is indeed an authentication and permissions related issue … Please, post the update part in your question as an answer and accept it to help future readers … Well done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CAUSE:**

The problem was on our end, not Ubuntu's. This was caused by some custom modifications in our setup that I didn't know about and were made before my time. Was a bit difficult for me to find.

Custom code was in: `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`, which then ran a script that executed `chown -R ${PAM_USER}. ${HOME_DIR}`. When users logged in as username@ad.foo this becomes `chown -R username@ad.foo. ${HOME_DIR}`. The chown command fails and user profile permissions are broken.

**FIX:**

Trimming everything after the "@" for the variable PAM_USER fixed the account creation process.

```
### Trim PAM_USER: :: zid@ad.unsw.edu.au -> zid
#   Students are logging in as zid@ad.unsw.edu.au which breaks chown below -> then breaks KDE login
PAM_USER=${PAM_USER%@*}
# ... this fixes: chown -R ${PAM_USER}. ${HOME_DIR}
```

Trim code based on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168371

Comment: Might be worth noting that the usage of a dot `.` as a `user:group` delimiter in the `chown` command is not advised ... it's very old and not portable and kept only for backward compatibility reasons ... Use a colon `:` instead.

Comment: Thanks Raffa! Honestly it's the first time I've seen anyone use that delimiter with chown